# What is the proper way to wait for Event with OpenEvent method in C++?

Tags: c++, events, event-handling

I have process A which creates Event

```
CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, L"EventA");
```

and then I have process B which is waiting for EventA.

```
WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
```

before above waiting, process B opens EventA with:

```
HANDLE h = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, L"EventA");
```

but I can't be 100% sure that EventA will be created by process A when process B opens it. So I did below:

```
HANDLE h = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, L"EventA");
while(h == NULL){
    h = OpenEvent(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, L"EventA");
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Is it the right way for Opening Event which is could be not created? Or is there something like WaitForSingleObject but for opening e.g. WiatForOpenObject?

Answer (score 0):

If N processes are starting randomly, then the way you used to wait for the master process (which is Event creater) to come up and create events is good enough.

But if we talk about good design of a software in which multiple process used to boot up, then there is always one process which spawns first and do initilzation stuff like: `configurations`, `event creations`, etc. first then it `forks` other processes which will subscribe the events. And this master process can perform various taks like monitoring, restarging of the processes.

So I think you need to re-think your design.

Comment: Good point, but I didn't mention that I don't have any access to process A, I can't be even sure that this process will be running on OS. Process A is completely independent from me.